# Detect if a file is added instead of modified in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, chokidar

I am writing a program in node to detect the files added to a disk. I can not use chokidar for the entire disk, it takes a long time if there is a lot of information. I am mixing chokidar with node-watch, when node-watch detects a file I add it to chokidar and I can follow the file. The problem is that node-watch detects only the updates (modification and creation) and I need to add the file to chikidar only if it did not exist (creation), but it is also added if it is updated.
How could I detect only the files that are copied?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 'update' watcher in both `node-watch` and `fs.watch` (which `node-watch` wraps, and which you could also use) pass the filename to your custom callback. Could you then use `fs.stat()` in your callback to retrieve the creation time property of the file, and use that to decide?

Comment: Thanks,I can use the creation time to know if a new file has been copied to the disk. If I save the date at the time the program is run for the first time, I can use this date to compare that the start date of the program is greater than the date of the copied file. But if I move a file from another disk, the creation date will be greater than the start date of the program, and it would not track that moved file. Even if I copy a file on the same disk to another place would be the same, I would follow it incorrectly because that file was not copied to the disk, it was already inside. Any idea?

Comment: Okay, but moving a file *will* change the access time (interestingly, I think, without changing the others). So I guess I'm suggesting that, between creation time, modify time, and access time, you should be able to distinguish between these different cases. And, as my math professor used to say, "I will leave the proof of this to you as an exercise."

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I did the tests (on Windows). When I move the files I can distinguish using ctime and atime, because if I move something from an external disk it is updated only atime and if it is within the same disk, only ctime is updated. But the case of the copies I do not have as to distinguish, because in both cases (copies in same disk or outside) is updated atime and birthtime.